# Gravitational wave behavior

Tags: gravitational-waves, interference, superposition

My guestion is since we have now detected gravitational waves can gravitational waves go through interference (ie destructive or constructive interference) with each other like other waves?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Happens When A Gravitational Wave Interacts With Another One?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110162/)

Comment: If the difference between this question and the one from 2014 is that this one talks about evidence from direct detection of gravitational waves, then the answer is that the waveforms we detect match up very well with theory, and the theoretical calculations do involve interference. Waves originating from different parts of the source interfere with each other.

Comment: @Ben Crowell  Does destructive interference imply that the wave can take on negative values--eg. troughs of a sine wave?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Gravitational waves can interact with each other like any other wave. They can interfere constructively and destructively. But doing Young's experiment using gravity waves is very hard. This is because creating a gravitational wave that can be detected takes huge amounts of energy.

Comment: Thank you that clarifys things so theoretically it could be entirely possible to increase and decrease gravity by using constructive and destructive interferece. I guess the trick is generating them which requires a lot of power like blackhole levels.